# Is it possible to get same Side Lower(Same Seats for sharing) for single PNR of two passengers in IRCTC - RAC ticket?

Tags: trains, indian-railways, irctc

I have booked a ticket for two passengers and the current status of the PNR are RAC161 and RAC 162. Our travelling date is 12-28-2018 from NCJ to MSB.

I'm sure that we will not get confirmed tickets and we are ready to share same Side Lower seat(Single Seat) but the question is Do we get the same seat with same ticket number or different seats?

We don't want to share our seats (even sitting) with other strangers, hence asking this question.

It has been a talk that two passengers with single PNR will get same seats to share. Is it true? I didn't see an Official details from IRCTC regarding this in their pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got same seats only. So it was a good Journey as I didn't shared my seat with Other strangers. So answer to my own question is **we will get Side Lower(Same Seats for sharing) for single PNR of two passengers in IRCTC - RAC ticket.**